# Is a dense layer required for implementing Bahdanau attention?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, attention-mechanism

I saw that everyone adds Dense( ) layer in their custom Bahdanau attention layer, which I think isn't needed.

[image]

This is an image from a tutorial [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/attn-illustrated-attention-5ec4ad276ee3). Here, we are just multiplying 2 vectors and then doing several operations on these vectors only. So what is the need of Dense( ) layer. Is the tutorial on 'how does attention work' wrong?

Comment: Can you highlight in the picture where the dense layer is? Or can you write equation showing how different the implementation is from the papers?

Answer (score 0):

A Dense layer inside the Attention layer logic is a must. This is typically a single unit, single layer MLP (though in case of Additive Attention, there is a provision to use more units). This layer helps us derive the attention weights during training

This Dense layer transforms the input (each of the encoder LSTM layer output) keeping the dimensions the same. This is then multiplied individually with the last decoder hidden state & softmaxed to generate the attention weights.

Multiplying the attention weights with the encoder hidden states help to magnify or diminish the relevant input information and this context can then be used for Predictions. (In Additive layer addition is used instead of multiplication)

Without the Dense layer in the Attention layer, we don't get the Attention weights. Without Attention weights, there is no context. Without context there is no Attention.

So in order to incorporate Attention, a single layer Dense MLP is mandatory. The model learns the weights of this layer during training. These layer weights are then used to derive the attention weights.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, dense layers are hard-coded into the Bahdanau attention. Let's break down the operation:

1. The attention vector i.e. the amount of attention the output $y^t$ should pay to the hidden state $h^{t'}$ i.e. the fixed length representation of the position $t'$, is calculated as
   $$a^{t,t'} = Softmax(e^{t,t'}),$$ where $e^{t,t'}$ is the similarity measure between the two entities.
2. While in a range of attention layers this similarity is defined a-priori as the $cosine$, **in Badhanau the similarity function is being learnt by a small neural network**. For this reason, you would combine the two (concatenate or add)  to pass it through a simple fully connected neural network:
   $$e_{Bahndanau}^{t,t'}= fnn(y^t + h^{t'}, n_{out})$$
   For a (t, t') pair, this would give you a "weight" to signify the attention that particular position of the input sequence must be given. You use this weight by multiplying it to your original hidden state $h^{t'}$ and you're good to go.
3. [Meta point] Great, now you repeat the above over the rest of your sequence position to get their weight to amplify/reduce their hidden state emphasis. Can you see a problem here though? *For every single $y^t$ output you now have $[0, ...,  t-1]$ hidden states.* To return to your original output size convention you generate the "context vector" as the sum of the weighted hidden states:
   $$ c_t = \sum_{i=0}^{T}a_{t,i}h_i$$

Hope it helps!

**References**: 
- Neural Machine Translation by Jointly Learning to Align and Translate, 2014 
- Effective Approaches to Attention-based Neural Machine Translation., 2015